# Conversion of radio emissions to decibels and role of impedance ratio to power ratio

Tags: rf, impedance, ferrite-bead, decibel, emissions

This question is about a web article about radio noise suppression by Ferrite beads.

[image: Plots of a family of four curves for the ferrite bead. Each curve depicts the relation of impedance to frequency for some value of dc-bias current.]

[The above diagram plots of a family of four curves for the ferrite bead. Each curve depicts the relation of impedance to frequency for some value of dc-bias current.](https://www.edn.com/wp-content/uploads/contenteetimes-images-edn-dc-bias-current-ferrite-bead.png)

To quote from the article: ["changing the current from 100 mA before you plugged in the USB device to 300 mA after you plugged in the device decreases the impedance of the ferrite bead at 100 MHz from 400 to 120Ω. Assuming that the emitted radiation varies inversely with the impedance of the ferrite bead, **you just increased the radiated emissions by more than 10 dB!**"](https://www.edn.com/all-about-surface-mount-ferrites/#:%7E:text=changing%20the%20current,than%2010%20dB!)

**Where did that 10dB number come from?** Is it because the author considers radio emission levels (units like using Volts) rather than using Watts and that is why the author used a factor of 20 rather than 10 when converting the emission ratio to decibels if used power units? (because based on the author's simplified assumption of "emitted radiation is inversely proportional to the impedance", relation between impedance and power doesn't involve a square factor so my assumption is using a factor of 10 is more prudent and sensible which causes ~5dB increase of radiated power emission.

I did a thorough web search but couldn't find any info regarding this other than this article which mentions ["Counter-intuitively, impedance is considered an amplitude and uses a factor of 20 when converting from Ohms to dB."](https://www.edn.com/how-to-think-in-db/#:%7E:text=Counter%2Dintuitively%2C%20impedance%20is%20considered%20an%20amplitude%20and%20uses%20a%20factor%20of%2020%20when%20converting%20from%20Ohms%20to%20dB.)

Is this related to the issue in the previous article? I mean did the 10dB come from the fact author raw converts the impedance ratio to decibels using a factor of 20 and used it as a measure of power ratio? But I don't see how that makes sense.

Furthermore, another question comes up. **Why does "impedance is considered an amplitude and use a factor of 20" which defies the original intention of the decibel conversion convention *(which I think is to make it easier to get a sense of how one ratio affects another different ratio like voltage ratio increase to power ratio increase)* to give the same value for relative ratios for both power and root-power quantities?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is as given.  Mind it's not very realistic, but it's just a hand-wave, and, it is what it is.

To motivate this with an equivalent circuit, consider the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBN3ro.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the large-ratio limit, the gain ratio goes from 1/401 to 1/121, or about the ratio of impedances, 1/400 and 1/120.

The voltage gain therefore went up (from left to right cases) by 400/120, or 3 1/3 times, or \$20 \log 3.33\ldots\$ = 10.45... dBV.  The power in the 1Ω resistance went up by the square of the voltage ratio, or \$10 \log 10\$ ≈ 10dB.

In practice, the dividing impedance might be a bypass capacitor to GND, following the ferrite bead.  A typical 0.1µF chip cap will have an impedance of a few ohms at these frequencies.

It's still not realistic that this will affect a direct path to radiated fields -- one would need a sizable antenna wired to this node following the capacitor, whereas most likely this is a short and tight loop to nearby IC(s) and the gain of this path (to the far field) is considerably smaller than that of, say, the cable itself; more likely poor grounding between cable shield and PCB plane, or a leaky ground (poor quality cable / connectors) dominates the far-field coupling situation, and this has no effect.  But one might apply the article's logic to situations where the filtered signal does, in fact, have a dominant far-field coupling (say, filtering on-board SMPS/logic noise away from an unshielded cable to some peripheral), and the figure will be more representative in that case.

It's also not the case that every situation will have this large-ratio limit.  Ferrite beads into cables, for example, see the impedance of the cable itself (typically mid 10s to low 100s Ω), and the change in ratio will be smaller.

So, like I said -- it's not an exceedingly realistic claim, but it's not meant to be taken perfectly at face value; at least, I would say so.  It's up to the designer to understand where it does, and does not, apply.  The more important point to understand is that ferrite beads are dependent, nonlinear elements, and not a salt-and-pepper design (and I use "design" lightly in that case!) element.

Comment: So as you point out author is most likely considering (though using a realistically inaccurate assumption) measured voltage levels of emissions. But can you also answer my second part of the question about the logic of " impedance is considered an amplitude and uses a factor of 20 when converting from Ohms to dB." Is there a reason for this unusual convention regarding impedance ratios? By the way, Thanks for the great neat answer.

Comment: Look closer. :) Notice the voltage ratios equal the impedance ratios, and dBV uses the `20 log`, therefore dBΩ should also use `20 log`.

Comment: In your diagram 1 Ohm resister represents radio emissions. The implication here is I think whether using a 10 or 20 conversion factor for impedance is context-dependent. In the context of my question, Impedance ratios are similar to voltage ratios and as power ratios are proportional to voltage ratios squared, 20 log is proper for impedance ratios. However, in a scenario where a simple device is considered by only changing impedance while keeping voltage constant etc. then impedance ratios are converted to decibels by 10 log because of relation to power ratio doesn't involve squaring.

Comment: So in essence it is the relation of the considered quantity to the power that determines the conversion factor of ratios of the quantity to the decibels. So by nature that is context dependent. Am I grasping this correctly?

Comment: In a CC or CV context, power in the element itself goes as I^2 Z or V^2 / Z, so should use the 10 factor. The rate varies for impedance dividers, which is why I was particular to note the high-ratio limit, where it goes to 20. For general impedance divider scenarios, dB should not be used with impedance because it's a nonlinear function. You can still have a ratio between scenarios but be careful to specify what parameter is varying and how, and preferably use a V/I/P measured into a known load.

Answer (score 0):

```
"you just increased the radiated emissions by more than 10 dB!"
```

As you look at this statement it is not mentioned specifically **10dBm** as if to suggest  relative difference to Watts, so why  assume it was a statement referring to the radiated emission levels in Watts ? I agree that the author should have been more clear about what radiated emissions he was referring to ...
A quick look at some [radiated emissions measurement techniques][1] suggests the unit is often in dBμV and this would make the calculation a 20.log() and not 10.log().
Mind you this also depends on what standard(s) are assumed when taking such measurements. In some countries and regions of the world the measurement units are dBm and in others they are dBμV, and one would use a conversion factor to convert from one to the other.

[1]: [https://www.ahsystems.com/notes/REM.php#:~:text=The%20units%20should%20be%20in,used](https://www.ahsystems.com/notes/REM.php#:%7E:text=The%20units%20should%20be%20in,used))%20they%20should%20be%20converted.

Comment: An "increase of 10dBm" isn't meaningful. The measurement is already ratiometric so it doesn't matter what the original quantity was: power gain, voltage gain, hotdog inventory... :)

Comment: The assumption is based on the author's original assumption "that the emitted radiation varies inversely with the impedance" which I incorrectly took as a reference to power as usually resistance and impedance are also inversely proportional to the power. But in composite scenarios like this such reference is not correct.  So as you mentioned author most likely considering dBμV ratios in his article so that's where ~10dB comes from.

Comment: Yes that's right ! the radiated emissions for 400Ω where some where at x dBμV/m and at 120Ω they were some where at y dBμV/m. The difference is about 10dB according to the author. So as if the radio emission levels were in dBμV/m and not in dBm ...

Comment: @Tim Williams : "increase of 10dBm" IS meaningful if you wanted to be precise about  the original measurement being in Watts, which most probably may not have been the case !

Comment: @citizen "increase of 10dBm" is incorrect because it applies units to a dimensionless ratio. 10dBm means 10dB relative to a 1 milli-watt reference floor. So 10 dBm means 10 milliwatts of power which cannot be derived purely from the ratios we are considering here. :)